# How to paste a block while creating the necessary lines to give room for the block solely?

Tags: vim

In VIM, text block yanking in Visual Mode, and pasting the block afterwards, paste it after the desired column given by the cursor, but pastes in-place, overwriting contents of the current and following lines.

Sometimes I don't want this, what I want is to paste a block with the indentation given by the  cursor position, but pasting inside new empty lines, without overwriting text.

Is there a way to do that?

Currently, to achieve this, I create a good amount of empty lines, and then paste the block, eliminating the remaining empty lines after (not very clever... ).

Note: I use `set virtualedit=all` to be able to paste at any column in the said empty lines.

Comment: I just do like you. I don't think there's a way to do what you (we probably all) want without resorting to vimscript. Did you search on vim.org?

Comment: @romainl, I didn't. I guess I will stick to the accepted answer map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like the following. Block-wise yank something, position the cursor and hit `<Leader>p`, whatever your leader key is.

```
function! FancyPaste()
    let paste = split(@", '\n')
    let spaces = repeat(' ', col('.')-1)
    call map(paste, 'spaces . v:val')
    call append(line('.'), paste)
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>p :call FancyPaste()<CR>
```

You can of course change the mapping to be anything you want; it's just a suggestion.

**Update:** Here's a version that accepts an argument. This let's you e.g. paste from the system clipboard instead. It also uses `virtcol()` instead of `col()` to take account for the possible use of `'virtualedit'`:

```
function! FancyPaste(reg)
    let paste = split(getreg(a:reg), '\n')
    let spaces = repeat(' ', virtcol('.')-1)
    call map(paste, 'spaces . v:val')
    call append(line('.'), paste)
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>p  :call FancyPaste('"')<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>cp :call FancyPaste('+')<CR>
```

Keep in mind it will only indent with spaces, not tabs. Indenting with the appropriate amount of tabs (and spaces if needed) would require some extra lines of code, but is quite doable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you could try this based on an ex command and the `=` operator:

```
nmap <leader>p :put "<cr>'[=']
```

Another possibility:

```
nmap <leader>p :let @"=@"<cr>]p
```

The `@"=@"` seems to make Vim forget about the lines being copied, character-wise and `]p` pastes reindented.

The [UnconditionalPaste](https://github.com/vim-scripts/UnconditionalPaste) plugin can also help you paste like that.

Comment: The accepted answer produces exactly the behavior I expect. `:put` solely don't, since it ignores producing indenting white space based on cursor position.

Comment: You are completely right, I totally forgot about that. I added `=` to reindent, I believe it should work for your use case now.

Comment: no, it doesn't, because I'm dealing with text, not code. So there's no smart indentation available, it just need to be white spaced based on cursor position.