# How can I insert multiple lines in front of the same number of lines in vim?

Tags: vim

Say I have two blocks of text. One is in my clipboard:

```
one
two
three
```

And the other is in a file I'm editing in vim:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

How can I insert the first block in front of the second block to get this:

```
oneAAA
twoBBB
threeCCC
```

I hope there is a way to do this in vim (something involving visual-block mode?), but if I can do this with another (*nix) tool I'm interested in that too.

As I finished writing this question I realized I can achieve what I'm looking for by using a google spreadsheet and pasting the blocks as adjacent columns, then pasting those back in to my file. I would still like to know if it's possible with vim though.

Comment: You can use the function I showed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860844/how-to-paste-a-block-while-creating-the-necessary-lines-to-give-room-for-the-blo/14861984#14861984

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you just paste the stuff in your clipboard into the file, to make the file look like:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC

one
two
three
```

then `ctrl-v` blockwise select the one,two three, press `x` or `d`

finally move cursor to the first `A`, press `P`

I didn't test, but should work

Comment: Perfect. I was almost there but I was selecting the block I wanted to insert in visual mode, not visual-block mode, and then trying to insert by selecting the beginning of each line of the target block in visual-block. Starting with a visual-block selection like you said works great. Thanks.

Comment: use shift+i instead of x/d/p to insert a certain text in front of each selected line. Comes in handy often.

Answer (score 2):

Text in registers have a type of either: `line-wise`, `character-wise`, or `block-wise`. When you yank text into a register and then paste it it keeps it's "type". So if you yank a line with `yy` and then do a paste, `p`, the text will be line-wise. This is typically just perfect, but ever once and a while it become convenient to change the registers type to something else. In you example I imagine you have copied the text line-wise but you want to paste it block-wise. You can "re-cast" the register via the `setreg()` function.

Example of casting register `a` to block-wise

```
:call setreg('a', @a, "b")
```

Example of casting the unnamed register to block-wise

```
:call setreg('"', @@, "b")
```

After re-casting the register you can just do a normal `p` or `P`. You can use `l` for line-wise, `c` for character-wise, and `b` for block-wise.

However if you just want to paste something line-wise it is often easier to just use `:put`

If you find yourself doing many register casting in your daily workflow it might be helpful to use Ingo Karkat's [UnconditionalPaste](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

With my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355), you can simply position the cursor on the first `A` in your text, and paste from the clipboard (`"+`) via `"+gbP`; the `gbP` is one of the special mappings provided by the plugin which forces the paste source to be *blockwise*, as if you had yanked it in Vim from a `<C-V>` visual blockwise selection.

Comment: You beat my posting by 7 minutes! I even gave a shout out to your plugin. I should have known better I can not out-post Ingo Karkat on a subject like this.

Comment: @PeterRincker Well, I was lucky, and (as usual), you're providing a great deal of helpful background information, whereas I just shamelessly advertised my plugin :-) Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words and for what it is worth I do use your UnconditionalPaste plugin. I find it quite handy.

Comment: @PeterRincker, if you want to out-post Ingo you have to chose some specific subject. For example, as a rabbid SPF13/Janus hater, I *always* have an edge on my arch-enemy! The downside is that, like every trend, they tend to disappear after a while so I'll need to find another niche soon. ;-)