# vim copy non linewise without leading or trailing spaces

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a mapping that will allow me to select a line of text non linewise so I can paste at curosr(not before or after) without introducing spaces that may have preceeded the line where it was yanked from.

This is what I was trying to do

```
 "copy non linewise
 nmap <leader>yy 0y$
```

Comment: I think it would be better to ["cast" your paste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323636/how-can-i-insert-multiple-lines-in-front-of-the-same-number-of-lines-in-vim/16324040#16324040) than it would be to yank differently. Make sure to check out [UnconditionalPaste.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355)

Comment: @Peter Rinker.            I saw that plugin but it appears to have every option other than insert paste at cursor.  The [p and ]p were already there in vim.

Comment: I would ask @Ingo Karkat. I'm sure a new mapping could be arranged

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker for the recommendation! In fact, the plugin's `gcp` already can do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nnoremap <Leader>yy ^yg_
```

`^` and `g_` are similar to `0` and `$`, respectively, but they exclude blank characters.

Comment: or my suggestion is `nnoremap y_ ^yg_`, because fewer keystrokes and repetition is slower than two different symbols most of the time

Answer (score 4):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) has a `gcp` / `gcP` mapping that not only flattens any number of yanked lines into a characterwise paste, but it also removes preceding and trailing whitespace.

The advantage of "casting the contents" only on paste is that you don't need to think about the future use while yanking, and as the original contents are preserved, you can paste the same register contents in various ways (linewise, characterwise, and any of the other flavors that my plugin supports).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could remap `Y` to yank until the end of string (similar to `C`):

```
noremap Y y$
```

Now `^Y` would do the job.